# difference between javascript validation and filter validation in php

Tags: php

difference between **javascript** validation and **filter** validation in php

Is it necessary to use PHP filter validation rather than javascript validation.

I dont understand what is the importance of PHP filter while using Javascript validation?

I read it as PHP filter  provide more security.

Is it necessary to use **PHP** **filter** along with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript validation is **browser side** and PHP validation is **server side**.

You should always use PHP regardless. Because JavaScript can be turned off in the browser.  That said, you can use JavaScript on top of PHP, as an extra layer to add more responsiveness for the user.

The typical way to do it is to run JavaScript validation first.  If things check out, then the PHP script will take a hold of the form data and do its own validation on it.  If the JavaScript validation finds something wrong, it can alert the user immediately without sending the data on to the back end.

Comment: No. Javascript validation is faster than the php validation because it run on browser

Comment: that i know...Javascript is faster than PHP filter.. My question is that PHP filter takes more loading time.. Does it affect the application performance....?

Comment: yes it increase the execution time. but for security reason PHP validation is needed. Affecting the performance of the application is depending on the amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript validation is on the client end, which can not be trusted since data you receive on server can be manipulated by a number of ways.

PHP Filters are provided to validated data on server end, where you need it. Its not that you only need to use the PHP filters, you can use your own functions also, but they are user friendly and helpful.

If you want ease of use to user then validate the data at both ends.